# Unable to delete worksheet from Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet

I am unable to delete a worksheet - no macro's/vba scripts. I had a pivot table, simply created a copy and now unable to delete after using the methods:

1. Alt + E + L
2. List item
3. Close/re-opening workbook

I tried searching all over the web and still unable to find a solution. I am not using any macro's or any VBA coding for this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about a right-click on the worksheet tab, then selecting `Delete` from the submenu?

Comment: Tried this method - did not work :)